# iMacros get text from HTML list

Tags: imacros

I am using iMacros to try and get the text from each list item.  My simple HTML looks like this...

```
<ul id="fruit_list">
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
</ul>
```

And my iMacros script like this..

TAB T=1
URL GOTO=file:///C:/test.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=ID:fruit_list EXTRACT=TXT

The result I get back is ...

```
AppleApplePearAppleApplePearBananaAppleApplePearAppleApplePearBananaGrape
```

When what I am expecting is...

```
Apple Pear Banana Grape
```

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy [EXTRACT](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#EXTRACT) Option that covers unordered lists that way... The simplest way to go about this is probably to extract the HTML code and parse that in Javascript with [SET/EVAL](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL).

It could look like this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=ID:fruit_list EXTRACT=HTM
SET neat_list EVAL("var e_s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'; e_s.substring(e_s.indexOf('<li>'), e_s.lastIndexOf('<\\/li>')).replace(/(<li>|<\\/li>)/g, '').replace(/ +/g, ' ');")
PROMPT {{neat_list}}
```

Using Regex to drop all the HTML Tags and additional whitespace to just keep the LI-Item Data you wanted.